# How to set background image on every page using group elements

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, grouping, everypage, fullpage

I need to put a background image on full page and I have several group elements, sometimes two groups on one page

I only get one Image on half of the page and on the next page the group elements start

I hope you can understand what my problem is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}

% colorize text
\newcommand*\ColText[1]{\textcolor{Goldenrod3}{#1}}

% a tabular* for each food group
\newenvironment{Group}[1]
{\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{0.9\linewidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
        {\fontsize{30}{35}\selectfont\ColText{#1}}\\[0.8em]}
    {\end{tabular*}}

% to format each entry
\newcommand*\Entry[2]{%
    \sffamily#1 & #2}

% to format each subentry
\newcommand*\Expl[1]{%
    \hspace*{1em}\footnotesize #1}

\begin{document}

        \backgroundsetup{          
            scale=1,
            angle=0,
            opacity=.4,  
            contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{exaple-image}}
        }
    \begin{Group}{group1}
        \Entry{entry1}\\

        \Entry{entry2}\\
    \end{Group}
    \vfill
    
    \begin{Group}{group2}
        \Entry{entry1}\\
        \Expl{expl1}\\
        \Entry{entry2}\\
        \Expl{expl2}\\
    \end{Group}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure whether I get your problem, so please make your code example compilable: Add a document class and `\end{document}` and provide the defintions for the `Group` environment and the `\Entry` command (or add the package that provides this environment) or, if this is meant to be a placeholder, use environments or commands that are available per default (such as `itemize`).

Comment: Note that the `mwe` package includes example images, so you can use those to replace images we don't have. Providing us with code we can compile to reproduce the problem is essential to getting useful answers.

Comment: There are two unwanted **8i** characters behind `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Should be removed, otherwise it will produce an error. Plus your own `Group` environment is still unknown if I run your code.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that, I had a template including these group elements

Comment: Then add the definitions of these commands to your example code. If the background image is always the same, it might be more straightforward to add it using `shipout` from the kernel.

Comment: Much better, but command `\ColText` inside the `Group` definition is still undefined and therefore throws an error.

Comment: Ok, now it compiles. But I get a single page with the picture spanning the whole page in the background and two `Groups`, one in the upper half, one in the lower. Isn't that the output you want? BTW setting `[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]` will stretch/shrink your image if it has not the exact relations of your page.

Comment: That's strange, I tried so many things and it didn't work. I get two pages, on the first the picture and on the second the elements

Comment: Did you also compile your MWE to try it? If the problem is limited to your main file, there might be some other setups/edits which alter the output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't know how but it works now